# Is there a difference between Scenario Testing and Functional Testing or are they synonymous?

Tags: testing, functional-testing

So I'm looking into introducing a more extensive testing process and I was reading about Functional Testing. I've worked with Scenario Testing before, but I'm fairly new to the term Functional Testing.

It seems that the two are synonymous, however I've not been able to find any information on whether they are synonymous or whether one is a subcategory of the other or whether they are two separate things. I've searched on stackoverflow, I've read the wiki pages for both, I've read some blogs on both and some university pages on both and can't seem to find the answer.

So as the title says; is there a difference between Scenario Testing and Functional Testing or are they synonymous?

Comment: They sound fairly synonmous to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scenario testing got introduced with [BDD](http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/Behavior-driven-development-BDD) (Behavorial driven development). So, basically while testing a single scenario, you will most of the times have multiple functional testing scenarios. The aim of Scenario testing is to test the scenario as a whole and BDD promotes it majorly.
Let me try to elaborate it with an example. So, say that a project is following BDD and the scenario to be tested is usually specified in the form of [Acceptance Criteria](https://www.leadingagile.com/2014/09/acceptance-criteria/) as below:

As an authenticated user, in order to withdraw cash, I should be able to use the ATM.

So, in this case to test this Scenario, you would need multiple functional tests to run. Listing few of them below:

1. Authenticate user
2. Enter valid cash to withdraw
3. Cash withdrawn

This just one flow and there will be multiple positive and negative functional tests involved in this scenario which need to be designed.
So, we can say that a scenario consists of multiple functional tests. However, they are not synonyms since Scenario testing can also include scenarios related to performance, usability testing etc. and is not just restricted to functional testing.
Hope I could resolve your query to certain extent.